# JQuery $.post never successful, why?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've made many different attempts at this so my mistake must be really obvious, my knowledge of JQuery isn't great but I've even tried examples straight from the internet, but I can't seem to get it, all I want to do is pass the variable "myLatlng" to a PHP file and echo the result of the PHP file on callback, currently the PHP file consists of:

```
$data=$_POST['coord'];
echo $data;
```

The JavaScript is:

```
$.post("/includes/eventgrab.php", { "coord": myLatlng },
    function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }, "text"
);
```

I have used firebug and myLatlng does hold a value. Please help

Comment: What response are you getting in Firebug?  Blank page?  404 error?  500 error?

Comment: Check your server logs to see if the post is actually getting there and not returning a 404 or other error code.

Comment: Rocket - Using Firebug just shows that the success function is skipped over.

Comment: Your call to `$.post()` seems correct as it is. I would check the URL as MarcB noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work fine assuming you have the `eventgrab.php` at the correct location (use firebug to see whether it is making a call nicely to that page) and you have a proper value in the `myLatlng` variable.

```
$.post("/includes/eventgrab.php", { coord: myLatlng }, function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `""` around `coord`, but it doesn't change anything, this is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Rocket: Absolutely correct ! I never noticed that. Tested now and it works with and without ". Thanks for pointing it out. I took away the wrong info from the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, your code worked! I think I also have a bit of a problem with my variable but I should be able to fix that. Thank you!

Comment: @Rocket: I too think so. I never use that way

Answer (score 0):

```
//PHP
$data=$_POST['coord'];
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$data);)//echo as json_encode

//JS
var mylatlng = $(".mylatlang").val();
$.ajax({
type:'post',      
url:'/includes/eventgrab.php',
data:'coord='+mylatlng,
dataType:'json',
success:function(data){
alert('data loaded'+data.data)
}
});
```